# Using undefined property in php class

Tags: php

```
<?php
class a{
    public function out(){
        $this->test = 8;
        return $this->test;
    }
}
$b = new a();
echo $b->out();
?>

output: 8
```

when i run this code, output the result 8 .

but when i add __set() function, it output a notice, and not 8 output

```
<?php
class a{
    public function __set($property, $value) {  
    }
    public function out(){
        $this->test = 8;
        return $this->test;
    }
}
$b = new a();
echo $b->out();
?>
```

output:

> PHP Notice: Undefined property: a::$test in /usercode/file.php on line
>   13

why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe check the manual?

Comment: First define $test variable in constructor and then assign $this->test="8"; hope it will work

Comment: Because *that's what __set does*. By default, PHP will create properties on the fly. If you've defined `__set` and it doesn't then set the property within the method, then the property won't exist, and will raise a notice when you try and read it.

Comment: I have no idea where line 13 is

Comment: @Scuzzy sorry，in “return $this->test;”

Comment: @iainn Is there any official explanation?

Comment: Good and very important question! I had the same. Thanks for asking, found my answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `a::out()` runs, there is no `$test` property in the object. [This is why `$this->test = 8;` invokes `a::__set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

But `a::__set()` doesn't create the `$test` property and the next statement (`return $this->test;`) cannot find it and produces the notice.

You should declare the object properties in the class definition and initialize them in the constructor (if appropriate):

```
class a {
    private $test;               // <-- because of this, $this->test exists...

    public function __set($property, $value) {  
    }

    public function out() {
        $this->test = 8;         // ... and __set() is not invoked here
        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

Without `__set()` being defined, the statement `$this->test = 8;` creates the `$test` property of the current object if it is not already created (by its definition or by a previous assignment to it) then stores `8` into it.

When `__set()` is defined, any attempt to set a property that doesn't exist or it is not accessible (setting inside the class a `private` property inherited from the parent class or setting a `protected` or `private` property outside the class) is handled by `__set()`. Your implementation of `__set()` doesn't create the missing property and it basically turns the statement `$this->test = 8;` into a no-op.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you said. But I want to know why my first program can run successfully.  Is there any official explanation?

Comment: @DeqinChen I updated the answer. Also read the [documentation of `__set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

Comment: `__set` IS invoked but it does not do anything, therefore, nothing is set. Thus the warning on the `return`.

Answer (score 10):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

Since you do not have anything in your `__set` body, the property is not created and therefore not available. You have to define the method body.

```
class a{
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
    public function out(){
        $this->test = 8;
        return $this->test;
    }
}
$b = new a();
echo $b->out();
```

Now THAT outputs `8`.

**Update**
You are asking why the first block of code works and the second does not. Take a look at PHP [source code here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5e8aa036f244570ad38f54e852a1aa249943a8d2/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c) and you will see the explanation in the code itself.

Looks to me, that when you do not have `__set()` in your class and you do `$this->test`, PHP internally calls it's own `__set()`, which does exactly what it does: *sets the property name to certain value*.

But when you define `__set()` with empty body, it overrides the default internal `__set()` and does nothing. And that is the main reason for your code to fail - the requested property has not been set neither by your `__set()`, nor by the internal one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you said. But I want to know why my first program can run successfully. Is there any official explanation?

Comment: @DeqinChen I actually updated my answer, linking to PHP source code as well, so that you could see the reason for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The following is true.

```
<?php
class a{
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
    public function out(){
        $this->test = 8;
        return $this->test;
    } 
}
$b = new a();
echo $b->out();
```

you should look at is [php overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Find the answers in the manual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you said. But I want to know why my first program can run successfully. Is there any official explanation?